# Fill an attribute with the escaped XML-String of a specific node and it's descendants

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a Template File, where the relevant portion looks like this:

```
<PipeSectionDefinition designation="Strang 1 RW/1-10" displayLastNode="true" drawMode="1" startPosition="0" pipeListId="xml:&lt;Pipes&gt;&#xD;&#xA; &lt;Pipe id=&quot;1A3352BC-8CFE-4D0C-BCCD-E30765B32821&quot; objectType=&quot;10000&quot; flowDirection=&quot;1&quot;/&gt;&#xD;&#xA; &lt;Pipe id=&quot;B9A3B241-C4DA-4925-BB4F-9564F645AEBD&quot; objectType=&quot;10000&quot; flowDirection=&quot;1&quot;/&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;/Pipes&gt;&#xD;&#xA;" pipeLayer.ref="76037019-658c-41d5-b422-017f91e36701" nodeLayer.ref="03e6f262-bdb4-4684-b4bf-bb239feaad95">
  <CrossingPipes textVisible="true" lineVisible="true" lineWidth="0" positionVisible="true" symbolVisible="true" textOPath="Concat('DN ', RefObject.Cast(GeoObjectLineBase).Cast(GeoObjectLine01).Hoehe, '  SO: ', FormatNumber(GeoHeight, 3))" />
  <NodeConnections lineWidth="0" />
  <PipeConnections textVisible="true" lineVisible="true" lineWidth="0" positionVisible="true" symbolVisible="true" textOPath="Concat('DN ', Profilhoehe, '  SO: ', FormatNumber(RohrsohleAblauf, 3))" symbolLayer.ref="679e499d-022d-475e-bd76-8c7f7fa1aad8" textLayer.ref="679e499d-022d-475e-bd76-8c7f7fa1aad8" lineLayer.ref="679e499d-022d-475e-bd76-8c7f7fa1aad8" />
  <InletPipes lineWidth="0" />
  <OutletPipes lineWidth="0" symbolLayer.ref="03e6f262-bdb4-4684-b4bf-bb239feaad95" />
  <PipePoints textVisible="true" lineVisible="true" lineWidth="0" positionVisible="true" symbolVisible="true" lineLayer.ref="67877b9d-2de9-4764-9201-d02fbce8148f" />
  <SpecialPoints textVisible="true" lineVisible="true" lineWidth="0" positionVisible="true" symbolVisible="true" textOPath="FormatNumber(GeoHeight, 3)" />
  <TerrainPoints textVisible="true" lineVisible="true" lineWidth="0" positionVisible="true" symbolVisible="true" textOPath="FormatNumber(GeoHeight, 3)" lineLayer.ref="dbc6c898-6686-4be0-bc9c-9d15517258a5" />
  <AttributeSegments lineWidth="0" />
  <AllAttributes distanceBetweenSectionLineAndText="20" textHeight="1.8" />
</PipeSectionDefinition>
```

There may be multiple of these `PipeSectionDefintion` Elements, but I just use the first one as my template. The interesting part is the `pipeListId` attribute.

My "data source" is this document:

```
<StrangList>
  <Pipes Bezeichnung="Strang 15b-SW" HaltungenOhneReihenfolge="0">
    <Pipe objectType="10000" flowDirection="1" Strang="Strang 15b-SW" Bezeichnung="7b - 7a" Reihenfolge="1" id="C9B982E1-82C0-4552-AF3D-03E3B9B8936A"/>
    <Pipe objectType="10000" flowDirection="1" Strang="Strang 15b-SW" Bezeichnung="7a - 7" Reihenfolge="0" id="CF363D66-8C31-43C2-A5B7-575D3A6D02F5"/>
  </Pipes>
  <Pipes Bezeichnung="Strang 16a SW" HaltungenOhneReihenfolge="0">
    <Pipe objectType="10000" flowDirection="1" Strang="Strang 16a SW" Bezeichnung="3 - 2" Reihenfolge="2" id="37D88A6F-D449-4296-B696-AE9FA129F9E9"/>
    <Pipe objectType="10000" flowDirection="1" Strang="Strang 16a SW" Bezeichnung="2 - 1" Reihenfolge="1" id="0693B8E5-108B-4877-BC02-10157C681FA3"/>
    <Pipe objectType="10000" flowDirection="1" Strang="Strang 16a SW" Bezeichnung="1 - 6a" Reihenfolge="0" id="FC683422-DC7C-4050-865E-C87D4B49BD79"/>
  </Pipes>
</StrangList>
```

Firstly, I would like to murder the person who puts an escaped XML-Document into the value of an attribute, but secondly, I need to make the same thing happen so his stupid program does what it is supposed to.

Unescaped, the value of the attribute looks like this:

```
xml:<Pipes>
  <Pipe id="1A3352BC-8CFE-4D0C-BCCD-E30765B32821" objectType="10000" flowDirection="1"/>
  <Pipe id="B9A3B241-C4DA-4925-BB4F-9564F645AEBD" objectType="10000" flowDirection="1"/>
</Pipes>
```

So as you can see now, my "data source" looks almost like multiples of that attribute, with some extra attributes. It shouldn't be a problem if they come along for the ride. So what I need to do is to convert each of my `Pipes` elements into an escaped string, prefix the "xml:" and then give that as the value of that attribute. My current stylesheet looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:import href="file:/C:/Java/xml-to-string.xsl"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Straenge" select="replace(document-uri(/), tokenize(document-uri(/), '/')[last()], 'Straenge.xml')"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="local"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PipeSections" mode="local">
        <xsl:variable name="template" select="PipeSectionDefinition[1]"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="document($Straenge)/StrangList/Pipes">
            <xsl:variable name="Pipes" select="."/>
            <xsl:variable name="PipesText">
                <xsl:call-template name="xml-to-string">
                    <xsl:with-param name="node-set"><xsl:value-of select="$Pipes"/></xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:element name="PipeSectionDefinition">
                <xsl:attribute name="designation" select="@Bezeichnung"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="displayLastNode" select="$template/@displayLastNode"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="drawMode" select="$template/@drawMode"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="startPosition" select="$template/@startPosition"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="pipeListId"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="pipeLayer.ref" select="$template/@pipeLayer.ref"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="nodeLayer.ref" select="$template/@nodeLayer.ref"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$template/child::node()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it uses the xml-to-string.xsl Stylesheet from http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/ with the templates that match `/` commented out. The variable `$Straenge` points to my "data source" file, which is next to the file being transformed.

Thanks in advance for your help, and let me know if you need more information!

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I feel your pain with having to embed escaped XML inside XML.

Comment: So what is exactly the problem, if you have that `xml-to-string.xsl` stylesheet and call its template to populate your `PipesText` variable, why don't you use its value to populate the `pipeListId` attribute? In general, as you use XSLT 2.0 and lots of people use Saxon to run that, be aware that Saxon 9.8 in all editions (including HE) supports the XPath 3.0/3.1 `serialize` function, so you would not even need to import a stylesheet for the serialization/XML to string task.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Please add that as an actual answer, since that has solved my problem. And my problem was that the stylesheet above does not populate anything, not the variable as I would think it should in it's current state, nor the attribute if I change it to that. But `serialize()` is the solution, since I use Saxon.

Comment: @Pipelynx, posted the answer with the suggestion to use XSLT 3.0 and serialize with latest Saxon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already use XSLT 2 you probably use Saxon 9 as your XSLT processor and as Saxon 9.8 (in all editions including the open-source HE edition) supports XSLT 3.0 and the XPath 3.0/3.1 `serialize` function (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-serialize) you might not need that imported stylesheet at all but could simply switch to the latest Saxon version and XSLT 3.0 and use e.g.

```
<xsl:attribute name="pipeListId" select="'xml:' || serialize(.)"/>
```

inside the

```
    <xsl:for-each select="document($Straenge)/StrangList/Pipes">
```

to create that attribute value.